# Error by the src attribute or assigned media provider

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, tiktok

I am attempting to import a video to a TIKTOK clone application from a link sourced from a Google Firebase API. However, the following error message appears when I press play:

> ERROR
> The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.

Below is the React code I am using with a function to handle the start of the video. The video is sourced from a URL on Firebase Storage.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./video.css";

function Video() {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(false);

  function handleStart() {
    if (play) {
      videoRef.current.pause();
      setPlay(true);
    } else {
      videoRef.current.play();
      setPlay(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="video">
      <video
        className="video__player"
        ref={videoRef}
        onClick={handleStart}
        loop
        src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jornada-dev.appspot.com/o/brecker2.mp4?alt=media&token=b5399418-9276-4e53-a706-1e00290c2c74"
      >
        
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Video;
```

Comment: It looks like your quota has been exceeded so the src URL returns "Quota has been exceeded for this project. Please visit the Firebase pricing page to learn more."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  I may assume whenever the request responds with an object or error, and not an actual media blob, it would throw that error that media type was not suited.

You could try fetch the blob with javascript first, check if there is no error, and the object type is indeed `mp4` and only after that set it to the src, thus being 100% sure of what type you pass to `src`.

```
  onError={event => console.log(event.target.error.message)}
```

[image]

Comment: gratitude, resolved.